# Get php variable to javascript from laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Im trying to send a variable from a controller to a JavaScript, I have my controller, and I can send an array:

```
public function index()
{

    $casa = new Casa(true);

    $result = $casa->where(['show'=>true])->get(); 
    return view('casa', array('casa' => $result));
}
```

If i go to my HTML and I make and echo:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <?php echo $casa ?>
 </body> 
</html>
```

I can show my array in the body, I was thinking about make an invisible element and get the array with document.getElementById().innerHTML, but I think this is not the best way.

Also, I think that I could make an Ajax petition sending a post and get the result, but I dont know if I can get my variable in a simpler way.

I tried to make and echo in Javascript and doesn´t work. some ideas?

Can I have 2 method post to get request in my controller? I already have one to get data from a form, and if I set the Ajax request I will have two post request. I would like have just one.

Comment: Go with the ajax solution if it's an array, and return json `response()->json($data)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeffrey Way created a package for that. He also made a video explaining it in laracasts.com. 
The package can be found here: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get `PHP` variable in `JavaScript` like this:

```
<script>
       var casa = '<?php echo $casa ?>';
</script>
```

you can use `alert` to see the result in popup dialog too:

```
<script>
       var casa = alert('<?php echo $casa ?>');
</script>
```